# nr_cpus boot parameter in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, smp

I was browsing Linux kernel code to understand the `nr_cpus` boot parameter.
As per the documentation, 
(https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

```
[SMP] Maximum number of processors that an SMP kernel
            could support.  nr_cpus=n : n >= 1 limits the kernel to
            supporting 'n' processors. Later in runtime you can not
            use hotplug cpu feature to put more cpu back to online.
            just like you compile the kernel NR_CPUS=n
```

In the `smp.c` code, the value is set to `nr_cpu_ids` which is then used everywhere in kernel.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/smp.c

```
527 static int __init nrcpus(char *str)
528 {
529         int nr_cpus;
530 
531         get_option(&str, &nr_cpus);
532         if (nr_cpus > 0 && nr_cpus < nr_cpu_ids)
533                 nr_cpu_ids = nr_cpus;
534 
535         return 0;
536 }
537 
538 early_param("nr_cpus", nrcpus);
```

What I do not understand the nr_cpu_ids is also set by setup_nr_cpu_ids.

```
555 /* An arch may set nr_cpu_ids earlier if needed, so this would be redundant */
556 void __init setup_nr_cpu_ids(void)
557 {
558         nr_cpu_ids = find_last_bit(cpumask_bits(cpu_possible_mask),NR_CPUS) + 1;
559 }
```

Initially, I thought this is called before the `early_param` invocation. After adding logs, I found that `setup_nr_cpu_ids()` is called after `nr_cpus()`. `nr_cpu_ids` is always set to the value sets in `setup_nr_cpu_ids()` in stead of `nr_cpus()`. I even verified its value in `smp_init()`.

Can anybody please clarify if my observation is correct or not?
What is the exact usage of `nr_cpu_ids`?

Comment: That does sound a bit strange as setup_nr_cpu_ids is called on line 531 here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L531 while the early_param functions are run at line 539

Comment: That happens because every architecture has a setup_arch() function implemented which calls parse_early_param().
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c#L983
setup_arch() is called on line 528

Answer (score 6):

As part of documentation describes from your question:

```
Maximum number of processors that an SMP kernel could support
```

Actually both of these function do the same. The `early_param()` provides ability to search the first parameter in the kernel command line and if the search was successful, the function which is noted in the second parameter of the `early_param()` will be called.

All functions which are marked with `early_param` will be called in the `do_early_param()` from the [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L416) which will be called from the `setup_arch` function. The `setup_arch` function is architecture specific and each architecture provides own implementation of the `setup_arch()`. So after the call of the `nrcpus()` function, the `nr_cpu_ids` will contain number of processors that kernel could support.

If you will look at the Linux kernel source code, you will note that the `setup_nr_cpu_ids()` function will be called from the [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L531) after functions which are marked with `early_param`. So in this case it is redundant. But sometimes it might be useful to get number of processors earlier.

For example, you can see it in the [powerpc](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/kernel/setup-common.c#L549) architecture. As described in the [comment](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/kernel/setup-common.c#L425) of the `smp_setup_cpu_maps()` functions where the `setup_nr_cpu_ids()` is called:

> Having the possible map set up early allows us to restrict allocations
>   of things like irqstacks to nr_cpu_ids rather than NR_CPUS.

Answer (score 1):

Typically arch detects the number of cpus available on the system. But, its possible to reduce the number of cpus you want to use. And, for that reason `nr_cpus` parameter was introduced. By default no one uses this parameter and in that case arch code is responsible for detecting the number of cpus available on the system i.e. for x86 arch look at [prefill_possible_map](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L1274), where a [check](http://[http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L1298]) is made to see whether `nr_cpus` were passed or not. If `nr_cpus` were passed then [that](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L1301) value is used. After arch detects the number of possible cpus available then `setup_nr_cpu_ids` in `kenrel/smp.c` finalizes the value of `nr_cpu_ids`. Do note that, it might sounds redundant but since it works so no one complains.

So, your observation is partially correct due to the fact that you missed the point, how arch smpboot code integrates `nr_cpus`. Hope this clarifies you understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I missed the prefill_possible_map function which changes the cpu_possible_max to be nr_cpus value.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `cpumask.h`, in particular this...

```
787 #define for_each_cpu_mask_nr(cpu, mask)                 \
788         for ((cpu) = -1;                                \
789                 (cpu) = __next_cpu_nr((cpu), &(mask)),  \
790                 (cpu) < nr_cpu_ids; )
```

`nr_cpu_ids` is the max usable cpus and `nr_cpus` that you pass as a boot param is used to set it. This is what it's doing for me in kernel 3.16.

The comment here

```
555 /* An arch may set nr_cpu_ids earlier if needed, so this would be redundant */
556 void __init setup_nr_cpu_ids(void)
557 {
558         nr_cpu_ids = find_last_bit(cpumask_bits(cpu_possible_mask),NR_CPUS) + 1;
559 }
```

is saying that if you have already set `nr_cpu_ids` that this call is redundant. The reason being the `cpu_possible_mask` has already been set to `nr_cpu_id`.